# How to efficiently compare two network endian u16 or u32

Tags: c, performance

The straightforward way to compare two network endian u16 or u32 would be to convert both of them into host endian and then compare.

But I'm working on a performance critical program and we have lots of those cases. So I'm wondering would it help if we just write a macro to compare them byte by byte from the MSB? In other words, by adding extra one (for u16) or extra three (for u32) comparisons, we can avoid two ntoh calls.

Would it help? Or would it depend on the hardware or the compiler? Is there any better way to do that?

Thanks

PS:
I understand the extra complexity needed while the performance enhancement may be small compared to the whole program. I'm just interested in how the hardware is working and how to push it to the extreme :P

Comment: Can you prove that the byte order conversions are actually a bottleneck?

Comment: Dang, @JonathonReinhart beat me to it... Have you already profiled the program was what I was gonna ask

Comment: If they are a bottleneck (which seems unlikely), why is that you can't cache the swapped versions of either operand? The only way I can see needing to continually swap the data is if you have a stream of host-endian data, and a separate stream of network-endian data, and you are having to continually compare data between the two.

Comment: If they're both network endian, why do you need to convert them at all?

Comment: Are you sorting, or just checking for equality? If just equality and they're both network-endian, there's really no need to convert - just compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you only need this code to run on one processor, which most likely will be little endian.

You need 4 compare functions, which you can write as macros. Two that compare the whole word (short or long) when network order matches processor order, and two that compare byte by byte for the other case. It's faster to compare directly than convert and then compare.

If you need individual compares for EQ, LT, GT etc and for signed/unsigned you may need a lot more combinations to get peak performance. I assume you know how to write the code so I won't try.

Naturally having done this you should benchmark the whole thing to make sure it was actually worth it! Unit tests are pretty important too, so not a trivial project.